What does the Linux 'ar' generated index file look like in a .a file?
I have an archive file generated by a xilinx archiver using:
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar -rs mylib.a
Looking inside of it using ar -t mylib.a
only shows a collection of .o files. But the 's' option is supposed to add the index file to facilitate linkage. What does the index file look like?

What do you gain exactly to see with the index file? But the 's' option is supposed to add the index file to facilitate linkage It adds an index "file" to the archive, it is like internal.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=formats-ar-file-format-big

@KamilCuk I just need to verify that it is there. Because my linker is saying it's not there. If it is there then I am building it wrong. If it's not there then I need to figure out why.

Is your question literally correct.  You use ar and not arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar -t?  The PC binaries may not be able to parse the crosstool libraries.  Is this the root of the issue?  Don't mix host tools with cross tools.

@artlessnoise I was careless with my question--yes. BUT: when I try to load the static library created by xilinx, in a different build environment, sure enough it cannot "see" the index file. So now I am trying to figure out how else to archive it.

@artlessnoise is it even possible to cross-compile a project but archive it using host PC archiver? Or do all the tools need to target the same platform?

I am not really sure.  It just seems that this error "index file issue" could be related to different versions/configurations of the tools.  GDB for instances can be configured as 'multi-arch', but the binary is bigger.  It is possible that ar can be build for only a single architecture (it is part of binutils normally).  clang is multiarch (like llvm), so often toolset/distros that support clang will come with multi-arch support.  At any rate, I would not rule out some incompatibility of different ar binaries (even if the version matches, it maybe configured differently).

ar seems a little weird.  It is like tar, but it also resolves symbols for the linker.  I guess gold (or gnu ld) call ar to resolve symbols.  Symbol mangling is arch dependant, but the 'tar' archive format is not.  I am pretty sure you could stuff random '.o' file into any ar (unless there is some check).  The issue would come when extracting them to resolve names.

@artlessnoise indeed that is when the issue is coming (linker complains about' no index found'. i'm creating a separate post on this. thx

The archive symbol table is usually named / or // or __.SYMDEF and is typically the first entry in the archive, from
https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ar&sektion=5 section Special Archive Members. I'll take libz.a from my system and I can see:
$ hexdump -C libz.a| head -n 60
00000000  21 3c 61 72 63 68 3e 0a  2f 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |!<arch>./       |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |        0       |
00000020  20 20 20 20 30 20 20 20  20 20 30 20 20 20 20 20  |    0     0     |
00000030  30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  31 36 38 34 20 20 20 20  |0       1684    |
00000040  20 20 60 0a 00 00 00 69  00 00 06 d8 00 00 06 d8  |  `....i........|
00000050  00 00 06 d8 00 00 06 d8  00 00 13 1c 00 00 13 1c  |................|
00000060  00 00 13 1c 00 00 13 1c  00 00 13 1c 00 00 13 1c  |................|
00000070  00 00 13 1c 00 00 13 1c  00 00 48 18 00 00 48 18  |..........H...H.|

The first entry is / with 1684 bytes. I can then extract the index file and "show" it to you. The index file "looks" like the following:
$ dd if=libz.a bs=1 skip=68 count=1684 status=none | hexdump -e '"%_c"'
\0*
i\0*
006330\0*
006330\0*
006330\0*
006330\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
023034\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
H030\0*
236334\0*
236334\0*
236334\0*
3158\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0*
331t\0001,310\0001,310\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001;004\0001t030\0001t030\0001t030\0001t030\0001t030\0001t030\0001177004\0001177004\0001177004\00012100\00012100\0001222034\0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001230 \0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001275,\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`\0001337`adler32_z\0adler32\0adler32_combine\0adler32_combine64\0get_crc_table\0crc32_z\0crc32\0crc32_combine64\0crc32_combine\0crc32_combine_gen64\0crc32_combine_gen\0crc32_combine_op\0deflateSetDictionary\0deflateGetDictionary\0deflateResetKe*
p\0deflateReset\0deflateSetHeader\0deflatePending\0deflatePrime\0deflateTune\0deflateBound\0deflate\0deflateParams\0deflateEnd\0deflateInit2_\0deflateInit_\0deflateCopy\0deflate_copyright\0inflateBackInit_\0inflateBack\0inflateBackEnd\0inflate_fast\0inflateResetKe*
p\0inflateReset\0inflateReset2\0inflateInit2_\0inflateInit_\0inflatePrime\0inflate\0inflateEnd\0inflateGetDictionary\0inflateSetDictionary\0inflateGetHeader\0inflateSync\0inflateSyncPoint\0inflateCopy\0inflateUndermine\0inflateValidate\0inflateMark\0inflateCodesUsed\0inflate_table\0inflate_copyright\0_length_code\0_dist_code\0_tr_init\0_tr_stored_block\0_tr_flush_bits\0_tr_align\0_tr_flush_block\0_tr_tal*
y\0zlibVersion\0zlibCompileFlags\0zEr*
or\0z_er*
msg\0zcal*
oc\0zcfre*
\0compres*
2\0compres*
\0compres*
Bound\0uncompres*
2\0uncompres*
\0gzclose\0gzopen\0gzopen64\0gzdopen\0gzbuf*
er\0gzrewind\0gzse*
k64\0gzse*
k\0gztel*
64\0gztel*
\0gzof*
set64\0gzof*
set\0gzeof\0gzer*
or\0gzclearer*
\0gz_er*
or\0gz_intmax\0gzread\0gzfread\0gzgetc\0gzgetc_\0gzungetc\0gzgets\0gzdirect\0gzclose_r\0gzwrite\0gzfwrite\0gzputc\0gzputs\0gzvprintf\0gzprintf\0gzflush\0gzsetparams\0gzclose_w\0*

That said, I do not find the "look like" very usefull.
